# 250G Disk space has filled up, but DiskInventory only adds up to 60Gs?

Tags: mac, hard-drive, disk-space

I cannot for the life of me figure out how my SD drive is filled up because I don't have any large files, especially enough to fill 250G.  I used DiskInventoryX to do a map of my drive and got this, a massive grey box full of "other" files, but they don't add up to 250G.  I ran Avast to see if there were any obvious trojans or malware of some sort: nothing.

What else could I do to figure out where this block is going wrong?  I have another user on the system, but its very similar... Definitely not enough to fill even 30G.

Thanks,
Jon

[image]

Comment: Boot up in [Safe Mode](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201262). It'll take a while to finish before the login screen. Safe Mode appears in red in the menu bar once you've logged in. Because many services are not started on a Safe Mode boot, restart after you login. In addition to other activities such as running a disk check, Safe Mode deletes many user & system cache files which may be taking up a fair amount room you cannot see on the disk in the UI. Last time I used this (today, in fact) a customer reclaimed 866MB in disk space. YMMV as to how much space you get back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hover your mouse over the large grey box and below it will show the path to that file.  Most likely it is your local TimeMachine backup data.

OS X will keep TimeMachine backups local to your system so that you can do faster restores or if your main TimeMachine system is not available.

From the Apple Menu, select System Info and then click the Storage tab.  You will see how much space "Backups" are using on your disk.

This space will be automatically cleared as you need more disk space.  It is not really considered used space from the user's perspective.  If you Get Info on your drive, the Used Space value will not include it.

For more details on this feature, see this [Apple Support Document HT204015](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204015)

If it isn't TM data or it is some other unnecessary cache file, and it is a file that you are sure you want to remove, right click on the grey box and select "Move to Trash".

And if you don't want local TimeMachine backups at all, open Terminal and type `sudo tmutil disable`.  If you need to re-enable them, type `sudo tmutil enable`

---

**FOLLOWUP 2016-04-19**:

The large grey box is "Space occupied by other files and folders" because you have the "Show Other Files" option enabled in the Preferences.  Those are system files that you don't have access to read, and/or files outside of the scanned folder. It appears you started at the top of the drive but it can't access the files/folders not owned by you (i.e. root).  You can see in the picture of the `.Spotlight-V100 folder` it has a red hyphen icon meaning you don't have access.

Since you can't [easily] run the app as root, here is another option but it will take more work.

Open the Terminal app and type the commands `cd /` then `sudo du -hxs .[^.]* *`. This will show the size of each directory tree. For example,

 `68M    .DocumentRevisions-V100
  0B    .PKInstallSandboxManager
2.0G    .Spotlight-V100
  0B    .Trashes
  0B    .dbfseventsd
  0B    .file
 44M    .fseventsd
  0B    .vol
 21G    Applications
7.0G    Library
  0B    Network
8.2G    System
292G    Users
4.0K    Volumes
2.5M    bin
  0B    cores
4.5K    dev
4.0K    etc
  0B    home
  0B    net
5.4G    private
1.0M    sbin
4.0K    tmp
1.4G    usr
4.0K    var`

You can then `cd` into each large dir and list the files with `ls -alh` or repeat the `sudo` command until you find the large files.

Do **NOT** delete any files unless you know exactly what you are doing.  All of the files/folders outside of the Users folder are for the system.  If you remove the wrong one, you will have a bad week!

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  It's not TM as I use Code42 for my backups, and when I go to "display files" for that big partition, its actually a bunch of smaller files that come up, none of them totaling more than 100MB in a single file.  That's my curiosity-- It's a SD disk so it shouldn't have fragmented data, so I don't know how its still showing full-- I am getting "startup disk full" which shouldn't come up either if it were TM data... Thoughts?

Comment: Because I can't put it all in a comment, I've updated my answer with more info and a different troubleshooting method.

Comment: Thanks! That helped quite a bit-- Found out that it was the new "DocumentRevisions" in `.DocumentRevisions-V100` that was taking up 100+ gigs... thank you!